# MESIBO Web(javascript), not receiving message in other end

Tags: javascript, websocket, chat, mesibo

I created two test users from *MESIBO API*, to test messaging between them.
Created exact same script in two files, and add send function in one file, to send message to the second user.
I tried the second user's *token, UID, and address* but the message gets sent from the first user but 2nd user's script listener doesn't catch it. Both the user tokens, appid (app name) are valid, I tried even in *HTTPS connection* too, but still couldn't receive a message on another end.

> **Second User (two.html) : Sender**

> **FIrst User (one.html) : Receiver**

> Script form first user: which supposed to get the message

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js"></script>
<script> 
var demo_user_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var demo_appid = 'legal.web';

var api = new Mesibo();

api.setListener(new MesiboListener());
api.setAppName(demo_appid);
api.setCredentials(demo_user_token);
api.setAccessToken(demo_user_token);

//api.setDatabase("mesibo");

api.start();


console.log('First User');

function MesiboListener() {
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnConnectionStatus = function(status, value) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnConnectionStatus: "  + status);
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnMessageStatus = function(m) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnMessageStatus: from "  
            + m.peer + " status: " + m.status);
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnMessage = function(m, data) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnMessage: from "  + m.peer);
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnCall = function(callid, from, video) {
    console.log("Mesibo_onCall: " + (video?"Video":"Voice") + " call from: " + from);
}


</script>
```

> Script from the second user, who send message to the first user using first user's token

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.mesibo.com/mesibo.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Send" onclick="sendTextMessage()" >

<script> 
var demo_user_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var demo_appid = 'legal.web';

var api = new Mesibo();

api.setListener(new MesiboListener());
api.setAppName(demo_appid);
api.setCredentials(demo_user_token);
api.setAccessToken(demo_user_token);

api.start();

console.log('Scond User User');

function MesiboListener() {
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnConnectionStatus = function(status, value) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnConnectionStatus: "  + status);
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnMessageStatus = function(m) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnMessageStatus: from "  
            + m.peer + " status: " + m.status);
}

MesiboListener.prototype.Mesibo_OnMessage = function(m, data) {
    console.log("Mesibo_OnMessage: from "  + m.peer);
}

function sendTextMessage() {

    let to = "2757b980f05600c48d75f17f6cb0480ed3a91557655dc7d2ebb3f2dc5vaa1cbe86178"
    var profile = api.getProfile(to, 0);
    console.log(profile);
    var id = parseInt(Math.random()*10000);
    profile.sendMessage(id, "this is text message");
}

</script>
```

[image: console from sender (2nd user) after sending message, status is 1 it means sent]

[image: But nothing in the receiver end]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using a token in the "to" parameter? It should be the address "USER_2". Please do not share your tokens in a public forum.

```
function sendTextMessage() {

    let to = "USER_2"
    var profile = api.getProfile(to, 0);
    console.log(profile);
    var id = parseInt(Math.random()*10000);
    profile.sendMessage(id, "this is text message");
}
```

Refer to the tutorial here https://mesibo.com/documentation/tutorials/get-started/javascript/

Comment: Thank you, my bad I was updating the changes in another file and was running another file in browser

Comment: Please update your original post and remove tokens.